# ComboBox SelectionChanged Event Firing on Preview

Tags: c#, wpf, events, combobox

So I have a ComboBox with a binding to a DataSet and I want an event to fire only when the selection is changed. I tried to use the SelectionChanged event but it fires whenever there is a suggested item. For instance if I type "eb" then "ebtoulson" would be selected with the "toulson" highlighted. My question is how would I disable this event from firing on the suggestion or am I using the wrong event? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you are typing and a suggestion comes up, you are actually changing the selected item so the event should fire.

What is your specific need to make this only work with the UI?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To you give you a little more insight, I have a customer form and I was wanting other form elements to auto populate depending on which customer was selected from the combobox. But as I mentioned, if someone started typing the name of a customer and it gave a suggestion of another customer with the same beginning letters it would auto populate the wrong information.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this solution. I don't feel it is the most optimal, but it covers your case. I'm using `PreviewTextInput` event to handle selection via text entry, and `DropDownClosed` to handle selection via the mouse. My `ComboBox` control is named `cbTest1`, and the code I've used is as follows:

```
private void cbTest1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var q = from i in cbTest1.ItemsSource.Cast<ComboBoxItem>()
            where ((string)i.Content).StartsWith(e.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            select i;
    if (q.Count() == 1)
    {
        // Have typed out a unique name match.
        var ActiveItem = cbTest1.SelectedItem;
    }
    else
    {
        // Name does not match or has multiple matches.
    }
}

private void cbTest1_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ActiveItem = cbTest1.SelectedItem;
}
```

It uses the Linq expression to determine if what the user has typed thus far has narrowed the selections down to a single item. However, the cost of that query may be too high for your case. Just try it out and let me know.